# invisible file?

Tags: ubuntu-one, mov

Everytime, after having started my computer, I get the following notification:

the file P(long number).MOV is being uploaded to you personal cloud.

Does anybody know what this means? I can not find such a file in my folder.

Cheers!

Corina

Answer (score 2):

The notification means Ubuntu One is synchronizing that file. The file must therefore be inside a folder being synchronized by Ubuntu One. The filename looks like a video recorded from a digital camera or camcorder. If you are synchronizing your `~/Videos` folder with Ubuntu One, it may very likely be in there.

If you keep seeing the same filename, it is likely taking a very long time to upload, or may actually be a different file being uploaded, but due to a bug (which has since been fixed), you may be seeing the notification with a filename that is no longer being uploaded. Can you please specify what versions of Ubuntu itself, and the `ubuntuone-client` package you have installed?

To see what Ubuntu One is currently working on you can open a terminal and run the two following commands:

```
u1sdtool --current-transfers
u1sdtool --waiting
```

These should print a list of the current, and pending transfers, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Be shure that the file is not hidden. To show hidden files presh ctrl + h. Then search for the file. Hidden file are preceded by a dot ".".
If you can't find the file, please make sure that the file are in the place you are searching.

Also you can try, in a command line:

```
cd / 
updatedb 
locate name_of_the_file
```

And will show you all the files matching this name.
If you haven't got installed "locate" package, please, install from ubuntu software center.

I hope it helps you!